# Printing to Dymo LabelWriter 450 from Access VBA

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access, dymo

We've recently upgraded some PCs and have subsequently come across some issues with the VBA code in an Access frontend we use to perform operations on a MySQL database. The specific piece of code pulls a serial number from the database and then prints it to a Dymo Labelwriter 450 as a barcode.

```
Style = vbExclamation + vbYesNo
Title = "Print Label For  " & Me.txt_Barcode & "  ?"
Response = MsgBox("Do you want to print a label for serial number " & Me.txt_Barcode, Style, Title)
If Response = vbYes Then
Dim myDymo As Object
Dim myLabel As Object
'On Error Resume Next
Set myDymo = CreateObject("Dymo.DymoAddIn") '
Set myLabel = CreateObject("Dymo.DymoLabels")
If (myDymo Is Nothing) Or (myLabel Is Nothing) Then
MsgBox "Unable to create OLE objects"
Exit Sub
End If
```

The code now breaks at line 8, i.e.

```
Set myDymo = CreateObject("Dymo.DymoAddIn") '
```

The error code I was getting was relating to ActiveX (which seemed possible that it might relate to going from 32-bit to 64-bit), but since installing the latest DLS from Dymo (DLS8Setup.8.2.2.996), it seems to have evolved to the following:

Run-time error '-2147467261 (80004003)

Automation error
Invalid pointer

I'm hoping someone can point me to an easy fix so I don't have to totally re-write the code!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this one in a couple of steps and to be honest, I'm not sure which exactly fixed this specific part of the problem:

First was to run the DYMO_Label_v.8_SDK_Installer

I also switched from the latest Dymo Connect to DYMO Label v.8

I then had to ensure the Barcode font we're using was installed as an admin for all users, rather than just a specific user profile

and finally, and I think this may have been the kicker, the software was looking for a label template called 'Serial.label' which I found on our server and copied and pasted into the C: drive where the software was looking for it.

I'm just glad I didn't have to re-write the code!